# How to mass create/efficiently make thousands of express js routes?

Tags: javascript, express, routes, url-routing

How would I mass create routes or efficiently make thousands of routes with express?

I would like to have routes that are of the format -
localhost:3000/${insert address here}

Do I make a for loop or is there some feature that express has built in? For example, yelp has "https://www.yelp.com/biz/mcdonalds-san-jose-19." I can't seem to find any resources about this.

Comment: That's a single route with a [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters). Don't create thousands of routes for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For thousands of routes that all have a similar form such as your example of:

```
https://www.yelp.com/biz/mcdonalds-san-jose-19
```

You create one route with a parameter and then that one route handler looks up the parameter (in a database or a some lookup table in your code) to get a pointer to the appropriate content for that tag.

You would implement a route like this with a parameter such as:

```
app.get("/biz/:location", (req, res) => {
    const location = req.params.location;
    // now get the appropriate content for that location using some
    // form of lookup and send the response
});
```

**Then, you have one route that serves zillions of possible locations and there is no need to register zillions of different routes**, one for each location.

If you weren't familiar with URL parameters in Express routes, the `:location` is a placeholder for some string that fits in the pattern there and a URL that matches this pattern will match this route and the route handler can access that parameter at `req.params.location` where the `location` property name comes from the name used in the URL pattern.  More details is explained in the Express doc [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

Answer (score 2):

From the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters):

> Route parameters are named URL segments that are used to capture the values specified at their position in the URL.
> [...]
> To define routes with route parameters, simply specify the route parameters in the path of the route as shown below.

```js
app.get('/users/:userId/books/:bookId', function (req, res) {
  res.send(req.params)
})
```

> The name of route parameters must be made up of “word characters” (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`).
> To have more control over the exact string that can be matched by a route parameter, you can append a regular expression in parentheses, e.g. `'/user/:userId(\d+)'`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create thousands of routes.
This is very easy to do using route params:

```js
app.get("/:address", (req, res) => {
   res.send(req.params.address); // req.params.address is the address in the route
})
```